# Issues to get a loop using a selenium library

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I did this code using Selenium and Pyautogui to clean an sharepoint List, based on a excel list. The first time the program is run normal, but I cant make the loop work, I have no ideia what i do. Someone can help me?

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(5)
num_repeticoes = 800
repeticao_atual = 0

# Inicialize o navegador Microsoft Edge
navegador = webdriver.Edge()

navegador.get("https://mdiasbranco.sharepoint.com/sites/Controledearmazem-MDB/Lists/movimentacaoPallet_JBO/AllItems.aspx")
navegador.maximize_window()

while repeticao_atual < num_repeticoes:
    try:
        page_loaded_selector = 'body'  

        # Esperar até que a página esteja carregada completamente
        WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, page_loaded_selector)))
        # aperta no title
        linktitle_xpath = '//*[@id="header15-title_1267"]'
        linktitle = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, linktitle_xpath)))

        # Clicar no filtrarpor dentro do title
        linktitle.click()
        
        time.sleep(1)
        botao_filtrar_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/button'
        botao_filtrar = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, botao_filtrar_xpath)))

        # Clicar no botão
        botao_filtrar.click()

        time.sleep(1)

        # mudapra planilha
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(x=114, y=236)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
        time.sleep(1)

        campo_filtro_xpath = '//*[@id="combobox-id__824"]'
        campo_filtro = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, campo_filtro_xpath)))
        pyautogui.click(x=1049, y=205)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.press('enter')

        # botao aplicar
        executar_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/button[1]'
        botao_filtrar2 = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, executar_xpath)))

        # Clicar no botão
        botao_filtrar2.click()
        time.sleep(6)

        # selciona todos para excluir
        pyautogui.click(x=338, y=437)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        # aperta os tres pontinhos
        pyautogui.click(x=790, y=267)
        
        # aperta em excluir
        pyautogui.click(x=795, y=304)
        time.sleep(2)
        # confirma a exclusão
        pyautogui.click(x=712, y=504)
        time.sleep(2)
        # tira o filtro
        pyautogui.click(x=1241, y=398)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=16, y=237, button='right')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=73, y=459)
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        
        repeticao_atual += 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro na repetição {repeticao_atual + 1}: {e}")

    finally:
        # Feche o navegador ao final do processo, independentemente de qualquer exceção
        navegador.quit()
```

I just wanna make this program do the loop, but cant do that. I did try many things, but only run one time and stop.

Comment: Because you quit the driver after the first iteration. Remove the finally block.

Comment: Do you mean, this part :  "finally:
        # Feche o navegador ao final do processo, independentemente de qualquer exceção
        navegador.quit()"  I did remove, but it continue with the same problem, only run 1  time and stop.

Comment: Do you have an error message? where the script stops and what happens when it does? you need to explain the problem if you want help.

Comment: Did you remove `navegador.quit()` as well?

Answer (score 0):

The **finally** statement here closes the browser.
remove **finally** and add

**while :**

```
 try:

 except:
```

**while True:**

```
pass
```